# Zendesk integration with Flutter

Tags: flutter, zendesk, zendesk-app, zendesk-sdk

I am creating mobile app with flutter and I want to integrate Zendesk SDK using flutter as i have done research and i get to know that zendesk can not provide support to hybrid apps the only provide native SDK but still there are some plugins which provide support but its too older and not working for me below is the plugins which i have tried.

[First Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/zendesk)

[Second Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/zendesk_plugin)

Here is the code from second plugin

```
await Zendesk.initialize(<account key>, <application id>);
```

But I am not able to run app in android below is the error which i am facing

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.zendesk:chat:3.1.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :zendesk_plugin
      > Could not resolve com.zendesk:chat:3.1.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/zendesk/chat/3.1.0/chat-3.1.0.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/zendesk/chat/3.1.0/chat-3.1.0.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
   > Could not resolve com.zendesk:messaging:5.1.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :zendesk_plugin
      > Could not resolve com.zendesk:messaging:5.1.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/zendesk/messaging/5.1.0/messaging-5.1.0.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/zendesk/messaging/5.1.0/messaging-5.1.0.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
   > Could not resolve com.zendesk:chat-providers:3.1.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :zendesk_plugin
      > Could not resolve com.zendesk:chat-providers:3.1.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/zendesk/chat-providers/3.1.0/chat-providers-3.1.0.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/zendesk/chat-providers/3.1.0/chat-providers-3.1.0.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 43s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.zendesk:chat:3.1.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :zendesk_plugin
      > Could not resolve com.zendesk:chat:3.1.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/zendesk/chat/3.1.0/chat-3.1.0.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/zendesk/chat/3.1.0/chat-3.1.0.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
   > Could not resolve com.zendesk:messaging:5.1.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :zendesk_plugin
      > Could not resolve com.zendesk:messaging:5.1.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/zendesk/messaging/5.1.0/messaging-5.1.0.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/zendesk/messaging/5.1.0/messaging-5.1.0.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
   > Could not resolve com.zendesk:chat-providers:3.1.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :zendesk_plugin
      > Could not resolve com.zendesk:chat-providers:3.1.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/zendesk/chat-providers/3.1.0/chat-providers-3.1.0.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/zendesk/chat-providers/3.1.0/chat-providers-3.1.0.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

can any one please tell me how to solve this or any other way to integrate Zendesk with flutter

Thanks

Comment: Have you found any possible solutions ?

Comment: @esentis Nop Still haven't found any solution regarding this

Comment: That's unfortunate, seems like we have to add the SDKs manually for iOS & Android and create the platform channels. All libraries about zendesk seem abandoned.

Comment: @esentis Yes we can do like this i have used LiveChat because this doesn't works

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no out of the box solution available on pub.dev for Zendesk as of end of 2023.

However, you can implement your own plugin based on native SDKs for iOS and Android.

For this you might want to look at this documentation as a starting point: https://docs.flutter.dev/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages
So you will have a Dart plugin code which will communicate via MethodChannel with underlying platfrom SDK depending on which platform you run the code.

I currently work on a project where developers implemented such plugin for their own product with Zendesk Support SDK and it works great in production for a few years already.